# BulkIndexError while using elasticsearch with Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the following code to load some data on elasticsearch in a Python module:

```
def loadNewsDataToElasticsearch():
    if not es:
        print('Elasticsearch server not accessible.')
    
    #Delete all previous data
    print('Clearing old data from Elasticsearch server.')
    indices = ['articles']
    if es.indices.exists(index='articles'):
        es.delete_by_query(index=indices, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
   
    print('Loading new data from csv file to dataframe.')
    df = pd.read_csv(directory+"elasticsearch/dataset/newsDataSmall.csv",index_col=0)
    dataset = {'title': df['title'], 'link': df['link'], 'date': df.index}

    # Elasticsearch bulk buffer
    buffer = []
    rows = 0
    
    #Testing
    #print(dataset['title'][0])
    
    print('Inserting new data to Elasticsearch.')
    for title, link, date in zip(dataset['title'],dataset['link'],dataset['date']):
      # Article record
      article = {"_id": rows, "_index": "articles", "title": title, "link": link, "date": date}
      # Buffer article
      buffer.append(article)
      # Increment number of articles processed
      rows += 1
      # Bulk load every 1000 records
      if rows % 1000 == 0:
        helpers.bulk(es, buffer)
        buffer = []
        print("Inserted {} articles".format(rows), end="\r")

    if buffer:
        helpers.bulk(es, buffer)

    print("Total articles inserted: {}".format(rows))
    #return(es)
```

The above code runs perfectly fine when I use it on Windows OS in Anaconda. However, when I am running the same code on Linux server, I get the following error:

> > > loadNewsDataToElasticsearch()
> > > Clearing old data from Elasticsearch server.
> > > Loading new data from csv file to dataframe.
> > > Inserting new data to Elasticsearch.
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/home/priyanka/final5-refined-pyc3.9.15/nlpfnews/semanticSearch.py", line 145, in loadNewsDataToElasticsearch
> > > helpers.bulk(es, buffer)
> > > File "/home/priyanka/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 524, in bulk
> > > for ok, item in streaming_bulk(
> > > File "/home/priyanka/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 438, in streaming_bulk
> > > for data, (ok, info) in zip(
> > > File "/home/priyanka/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 355, in _process_bulk_chunk
> > > yield from gen
> > > File "/home/priyanka/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 274, in _process_bulk_chunk_success
> > > raise BulkIndexError(f"{len(errors)} document(s) failed to index.", errors)
> > > elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: 500 document(s) failed to index.

I am stuck with this for the past few days and have not been able to resolve it. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you catch the exception `BulkIndexError`, and check the errors of why 500 documents can not index but the other 500 documents can be indexed?

Comment: On the other side, inside the index is there any indexed document?

Comment: @hkulekci Yes, I tried that and it indexes 1 one document and then fails to index the next. It is alternating. The only Exception it throws is: Document(s) failed to index.

Comment: @hkulekci Please ignore my previous comment. It is not indexing any of the documents. It only says Document failed to index.

Comment: I thought that you can get an error related to mapping, maybe? Some documents can have different field types when we compare them with previously indexed documents. Ist there anything something like this?